# Modelling problem: How to get rid of "Edgeless Edge"

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

Okay, so when I'm modelling and making the general shape (or any shape) from my mesh, sometimes when I would form it into a certain way it would act like it was "inverted" or something and make this "Edgeless Edge". It shows no actual edge line. Is there anyway to get rid of these edges or faces?

Pic for reference on what I mean below.

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejzba.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the result of a highly non-coplanar face.

In that case, the edge is of one of the triangles created not by you, but by the viewport renderer in the course of giving you a shaded image.You could make the edge explicit by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> - 'Triangulate Faces'.

Comment: Do I have to select the vertices and then Control T? Or will it affect the mesh overall? Also which do I edit? Quad method or Polygon Method? and which type in that method should I chose?

Comment: You don't really want topology like this at all, in the end.. ( if you'd wanted that edge in the first place, you'd have put it there ).. the triangulate is just to expose the edge. So it's Face Mode >  select the face > Ctrl-T > (any way that shows the edge). In every example I've tried, the triangulation method doesn't make  a difference? If I'm repairing this sort of occurrence, I usually kick off by deleting the face anyway.